# Converting pegjs to C++

Tags: c++, parsing, peg, pegjs

I have used pegjs to create a parser, quite similar actually to the example [shown here](https://pegjs.org/online) for a custom string-formatting function.

I would like to port this to C++. What might be the best way to do this? Are there are existing parsers in C/C++ that are compliant with the pegjs grammar? Or, would I want to transpile the generated JS with something like V8, or what might be a possible route to do this conversion, aside from manually rewriting everything from scratch?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_parser_generators#Parsing_expression_grammars,_deterministic_boolean_grammars

Comment: parsing expression grammars are basically just a fancy name for recursive descent parsers that handle disjunction using "first match" rather than longest match etc. there are lots of recursive descent parser frameworks for C++.  Boost.Spirit for example.